# Issue trying to use function from DateTimeHelper class: "timeAgoInWords() is not defined"

Tags: error

Not quite sure how to use functions defined in Helper classes in my templates. For example, trying to use "timeAgoInWords" on an entry's dateCreated attribute. I get an internal server error and a "Unknown "timeAgoInWords" function" message when I try to visit the page. It occurs to me that perhaps I have to include or import the DateTimeHelper class? I'm not sure how to go about this.

Here's a link to the Craft docs on the package that I'm trying to include:

https://craftcms.com/classreference/helpers/DateTimeHelper

I'm trying to include the timeAgoInWords function in my index.html template within the templates folder.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, only [Variable](https://craftcms.com/classreference#craft.app.variables) classes are exposed to templates in Craft and there isn't a Variable wrapper for [DateTimeHelper](https://craftcms.com/classreference/helpers/DateTimeHelper).

However, that would be a super-simple [plugin](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/introduction) to write that exposes `timeAgoInWords` as a Twig [filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation) so you could do something like

```
entry.postDate|timeAgoInWords
```